# Why is a question about a network switch off topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Removing a non-running device from a network switch breaks Windows file sharing](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82774/removing-a-non-running-device-from-a-network-switch-breaks-windows-file-sharing)

I’m confused why this question is considered off topic. I didn’t ask about the server mentioned. I ask about the connection of the server to a network switch. I suspect that the answer probably pertains to the packet switching done by the switch, and as I understand it that is OSI layer 3. Also, I don’t know many consumers who use a network switch, let alone a 24-port one. The community radio station I volunteer at is a registered business, so it is not a consumer environment.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about why a protocol above OSI layer-4 quit working when you removed the device. Windows file sharing is above OSI layer-4, and it has to do with your host/server OS configurations.

> I suspect that the answer probably pertains to the packet switching
> done by the switch, and as I understand it that is OSI layer 3.

I believe you are confused about some things. Switching is done on frames (not packets) at layer-2. Packet switching is done by routers at layer-3.

Also, the removed device is a consumer-grade device, despite it being used in a business network. Simply removing the server device, causing a protocol above OSI layer-4 to stop working on a host is not a network problem, it is a host/server problem with a protocol above OSI layer-4.

As I explained in my comment to the question, you can ask about this on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) for a business network